# How to set shortcut target to current folder

Tags: command-line, file-shortcut

I want to be able to launch a software on the current folder the shortcut is located. By including the folder path at the end of the "Target" property of the shorcut, I already manage to do that. However, I want this part to be automatic, so that if I move the shortcut to another folder it will start the software on *that* folder without the need to manually copy and paste the path in the target.

Is this possible? I have been researching for many hours now and I cannot find the specific answer. I have tried adding `cd`, `%cd%`, both iterations with and without " around them and nothing works. I am very unexperienced on the command line so I beg for your help.

The final objective here, in case you're wondering, is to use this parameter in the Easy Context Menu software, which allows me to add options to context menus. I want to be able to open my desired software (Bulk Rename Utility) by right clicking within any folder and already have the current folder path in the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The code is simple:

```
set address="C:\Program Files\[program folder]\[executable name].exe" %CD%
%address%
```

This is saved on a batch file, which I launch by right clicking inside any folder and clicking the option on the context menu. To add it to the context menu, I used Easy Context Menu and included the .bat in the folder menu section, without any parameters.